# WSO2 GR fails to start with Carbon SecureVault enabled

Tags: java, wso2

I am running a WSO2 GR install, which is working perfectly. However, when I try to enable SecureVault using the direction below, the server fails to start. The only output in wso2carbon.log is :

```
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,307]  WARN {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler} -  SecretManager has not been initialized.Cannot collect secrets. {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,315]  WARN {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler} -  SecretManager has not been initialized.Cannot collect secrets. {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,317]  WARN {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler} -  SecretManager has not been initialized.Cannot collect secrets. {org.wso2.securevault.secret.handler.SecretManagerSecretCallbackHandler}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon... {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64, amd64 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.6.0_45 {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,366]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.45-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc. {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,367]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /opt/wso2/gr {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,367]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /opt/wso2/gr/tmp {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,367]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : wso2, en-US, Europe/Amsterdam {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,451]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator} -  Could not validate the system for configuration parameter : certFingerprint {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.SystemValidator}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,453]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  RAM size (MB): 1500 of the system is below the recommended minimum size :2048 {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,466]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created ! {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:12,491]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS}
TID: [0] [Greg] [2013-12-19 13:44:23,209]  INFO {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule} -  TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined {org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule}
```

I configured SecureVault using the following steps:

1. Change the password on the `repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks`, `repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks` key stores
2. Change the password of the wso2carbon private key in wso2carbon.jks key store.
3. Modify `repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`, in the Connector protocol section for the SSL connector add:

   ```
   keystoreFile="/opt/wso2/gr/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks"
   keystorePass="newPassword"
   keyAlias="wso2carbon"`
   ```
4. Fill the `repository/conf/security/cipher-text.properties` file with the following content:

   ```
   Carbon.Security.KeyStore.Password=[newPassword]
   Carbon.Security.KeyStore.KeyPassword=[newPassword]
   Carbon.Security.TrustStore.Password=[newPassword]
   Datasources.WSO2_CARBON_DB.Configuration.Password=[newPassword]`
   ```
5. Run `bin/ciphertool.sh -Dconfigure`. This seems successful.
6. Put the password in a file called `password` in the WSO2 base dir
7. Restart the GR

After these steps, I get the output as listed above.

Does anyone know how to solve this or where to get more info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you start server as background process or just running server in the console...?  If you start with background then you need to create a tmp file (password-tmp in CARBON_HOME directory) to provide the master password. If you start just server running script then you are promoted to enter the master password, You can provide it in command line. You can find more details from [here](http://soasecurity.org/2012/08/12/secure-plain-text-passwords-in-wso2-carbon-configuration-files/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a Linux environment, create a file called run.sh, and add the script mentioned below. Then, execute the script with ./run.sh. It will fetch the secure-vault password to the wso2server.sh process. If you need, you can further modify this to ask the password from the user instead of hard-coding it.

```
$ cat ~/wso2esb-4.0.2/run.sh

#!/bin/sh
cat > password << EOF
securevaultPassword
EOF
nohup ./bin/wso2server.sh -DapplyPatches
tail -f nohup.out
```